# When did each opcode get added to the EVM?

Tags: opcode, forks

After the original set defined in the Ethereum yellow paper,
many new opcodes have been added.

I'm after a list of when each one was added (by fork).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- byzantium, 2017/10: +4

  - `REVERT` added, [EIP-140](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-140)
  - `STATICCALL` added, [EIP-214](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-214)
  - `RETURNDATACOPY` added, [EIP-211](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-211)
  - `RETURNDATASIZE` added, [EIP-211](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-211)
- constantinople, 2018/12: +5

  - `CREATE2` added, [EIP-1014](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1014)
  - `EXTCODEHASH` added, [EIP-1052](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1052)
  - `SHL` added, [EIP-145](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-145)
  - `SHR` added, [EIP-145](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-145)
  - `SAR` added, [EIP-145](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-145)
- istanbul, 2019/12: +2

  - `CHAINID` added, [EIP-1344](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1344)
  - `SELFBALANCE` added, [EIP-1884](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1884)
- london, 2021/08: +1

  - `BASEFEE` added, [EIP-3198](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3198)
- shanghai, 2023/03: +1

  - `SELFDESTRUCT` deprecated, [EIP-6049](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-6049), [EIP-4758](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4758)
  - `PUSH0` added, [EIP-3855](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3855)

Sources:

- [`evm.codes`](https://www.evm.codes/) main table
- [`eips.ethereum.org`](https://eips.ethereum.org/) various EIPs
- [`blog.ethereum.org`](https://blog.ethereum.org/) various HF announcements